# android log file generated after 23:59 from batch file doesn't work

Tags: android, batch-file, debugging, logging, logcat

I generate android log file with bat every 5 minutes. The format of the generated file is like this: 20170216_235901.txt. It fails to generate file after 23:59.
This pic shows the files generated. You can see the timestamp of the generated file of the next day is missed after 23:59 and it is not in .txt format.

[image]

My code for the bat is like this:

```
:LOOP  
adb logcat -v time -d *:E >     C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\backup\%date:~-10,4%%date:~-5,2%%date:~-2,2%_%time:~    0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt &
timeout /t 300 
goto :LOOP
```

What caused this? and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it start working correctly again around 10 AM?

Comment: No, it doesn't work since 23:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue appears to be the final filename in your list - `20170216_` created `8:55`

I'd suggest that you "quote the generated filename" (ie `...>"C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\backup\%date:~-10,4%%date:~-5,2%%date:~-2,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt" &...` because it would appear that the destination filename includes a space, so only the first part will be used as the filename, and that file will be overwritten every 5 minutes until `10:00` when the hours will again have two digits (Hence the dark one's question)

Comment: That's what I was trying to hint at